# Can MorphologicalComponents be mapped to a list of images?

Tags: image-processing

The example in the documentation shows that this function can only be applied to one single binary image as follows:

```
MorphologicalComponents[image1]//Colorize
```

I tried this :

```
Map[ MorphologicalComponents[#]&,{imag1,Image2,...Image n]//Colorize
```

and this:

```
MorphologicalComponents[#]&/@{imag1,Image2,...Image n]//Colorize
```

But I am only getting large outputs instead of colorized images. Is what I am trying do feasible  at all?

Many Thanks.

Comment: `Colorize /@ MorphologicalComponents /@ {image1, image2, image3}` or `MorphologicalComponents /@ {image1, image2, image3} // Colorize /@ # &`?

Comment: @kglr. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using two images from the docs:

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
image1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFMx8.png"];
image2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWZQp.png"];
images = {image1, image2}
```

You can compose `Colorize` and `MorphologicalComponents` and map the composition on your list of images:

```
Composition[Colorize, MorphologicalComponents] /@ images
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you can map `Colorize` on the output of `MorphologicalComponents/@images`:

```
Colorize /@ MorphologicalComponents /@ images
```

to get the same result.